# How to delete one specific stream out of two audio streams from multiple video files of same properties using python?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, video, ffmpeg, automation

I have a folder with 200(or more) video files, each approximately 70MB in size(which doesn't matter), and contain one video, one text and two audio streams, and audio streams belong to two different languages. All the files have the same two language audio streams. So how to delete one specific audio stream of the language of user's choice, from each file, and keep everything else intact. For a single file, I could've used mkvcleaver or some other GUI tools. Or even ffmpeg. But as its repetitive, as in Zen of python, I am thinking it could be automated. How do I do it in Python 3.4?

Comment: This feels like two separate questions:
(1) How to use a command-line tool like `ffmpeg` to strip an audio stream out of a video file (what format, BTW?), and 
(2) How to automate this for files found in a specific location (are they all under one directory? sub-directories?)

Both are do-able, but perhaps add some details and/or split the question.

Comment: There is no (1).  I just need the (2) to loop the (1).

Comment: So you need to explain the problem then: what the inputs are, what the expected outputs are, what command line you're already using to do (1), unless you're actually proposing doing the video processing directly in Python, which I would **not** recommend for a quick tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.
I used mkvtoolnix command for removing the audio with ID:1.
Made a list using os.listdir()
And then for the given format files, looped it with subprocess.call() function, just substituting the filenames from listdir(). It worked. Thank you for your support. I welcome edits, this is my first time here.

```
import os

from subprocess import call

files = os.listdir("D:\\Media\\TV Shows\\Naruto")

frmt = input('Enter the file format:')

files = [i for i in files if i[-3:]==frmt ]

print(files)
for filegoeshere in files:
    fun = '''"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "D:\\Media\\TV Shows\\Naruto\\'''+filegoeshere[:-4]+'''_jp.mkv"  "--default-track" "0:yes" "--forced-track" "0:no" "--display-dimensions" "0:640x480" "--language" "2:jpn" "--track-name" "2:Japanese" "--default-track" "2:no" "--forced-track" "2:no" "--track-name" "3:English" "--default-track" "3:yes" "--forced-track" "3:no" "-a" "2" "-d" "0" "-s" "3" "-T" "--no-global-tags" "D:\\Media\\TV Shows\\Naruto\\'''+filegoeshere+'''" "--track-order" "0:0,0:2,0:3"'''
    call(fun)
```